# Locating NSZombie in code with instruments

Tags: xcode, xcode7, instruments, dealloc, nszombie

I have an error, that appears in 100% of use cases in certain scenario. 
Current state:

1. Exception breakpoint is enabled.
2. Zombie objects are enabled in run schemes.
3. I use Instruments Zombie tool to trace the error.

Here is the problem.
Before making step 3 I found that the issue appears when deallocated `CALayer` calls `-superlayer` method:

> 2016-07-12 22:59:14.503 TestIOS[29904:768808] *** -[CALayer
>   superlayer]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7b733410

When I run app in Instruments everything goes fine until the moment, where error appears. However, the only thing that Instruments Console prints in the end is:  `<End of Run>`.
According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/EradicatingZombies.html) `Zombie Messaged dialog` should appear when app crashes. But it doesnt't. And the black "stop" button switches to red "start" circle.

This dialog window should provide button to jump to Zombie object in code. How can I do it if nothing appears?

[[image: Instruments screenshot[2]]

Comment: No, that arrow appears next to the mouse location. Mouse disappears when making screenshots.

Comment: In record settings I have enabled everything except: "Discard events for freed memory", "Only track VM allocations".

Comment: "Discard events for freed memory" was disabled as I wrote. And I meant exactly the same row with "VM: Memory Tag 255". It has an arrow on the right only because mouse was set in that row.